# Dynamic tabs in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm using scrollable tab view https://github.com/skv-hea…/react-native-scrollable-tab-view Js, for tabs, the sample example works fine, but i have an dynamic array of data, so the tabs needs to be based on the data. I couldnt find dynamic example on github or on google.

i have this array of data

```
[
{
"id": 1,
"name": "Indian",
"avatar_url": "ddddd",
"menu_items": [
{
"id": 7,
"name": "zzzzz",
"price_cents": 0,
"price_currency": "USD",
"avatar_url": "image.com"
},
{
"id": 4,
"name": "ccccc",
"price_cents": 0,
"price_currency": "USD",
"avatar_url": "image.com"
}]
```

The tab name should be indian and the contents inside will be menu items, i searched about it but nothing helped, and there is no documentation on dynamic data. I believe this is possible, but how can this be done?

I tried this way

```
    <ScrollableTabView dataArray={this.state.categories}
    renderTabBar={(category) => <ScrollableTabBar category={category}/>}>
      <Text tabLabel='Tab #1'>{category}</Text>
    </ScrollableTabView>
```

but couldnt get category value

Comment: can u pls paste some more lines of code like state declaration..?

Comment: @SantoshSharma followed this example https://github.com/skv-headless/react-native-scrollable-tab-view/blob/master/examples/FacebookTabsExample/DynamicExample.js set an initial tabs working, but after fetching from server tabs is not rerendering

Comment: Could you please elaborate more.. your question was not clear to me.